# Why the react table is not rendering my data?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to showed data use React Table on react js and I followed the instruction from a website. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import './App.css';
import ReactTable from "react-table";  


class App extends Component {  
  render() {  
     const data = [{  
        name: 'Ayaan',  
        age: 26  
        },{  
         name: 'Ahana',  
         age: 22  
         },{  
         name: 'Peter',  
         age: 40      
         },{  
         name: 'Virat',  
         age: 30  
         },{  
         name: 'Rohit',  
         age: 32  
         },{  
         name: 'Dhoni',  
         age: 37  
         }]  
     const columns = [{  
       Header: 'Name',  
       accessor: 'name'  
       },{  
       Header: 'Age',  
       accessor: 'age'  
       }]  
    return (  
      <ReactTable  
      data={data}  
      columns={columns}  
      defaultPageSize = {2}  
      pageSizeOptions = {[2,4, 6]}  
      >  
      </ReactTable>      
    )  
  }  
}  
export default App;
```

But I got some error like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLk1s.png)

here is my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-table": "^7.0.4"
  }
```

I do know what this the version give me some trouble or not.

Comment: this is the error from the image:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Check all the imports. You probably included some extra curly braces somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an old example. Please follow: [How to create a Simple react-table](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/basic)